# Jmeter Performance testing

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to send Json bulk request in .Json file.

**Ex:**

```
{
"company name":"sanket",
"csds":[  

       {  
               "id":"1",
               "firstname":"abc",
               "lastnamne":"xyz"
        },
        {  
               "id":"2",
               "firstname":"abc",
               "lastnamne":"xyz"
        }

        ]
}
```

How to send json file in jmeter. we have to write any code for reading json objects from file ?? or any sampler is there which directly read bulk requests?? 
After executing the testplan i want to see the data in request tab of view results tree.

Thanks,
Sanket

Comment: You have shared JSON request content. Can you shared more details about your JSON request and test scenario. What exactly are your test requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write any code, JMeter provides [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function so you can use it right in your request body

1. Switch your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to "Body Data" view
2. Place [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function there providing absolute or relative path to the JSON file

   [image: FileToStringRequestBody]

Some more tips:

- Use [Function Helper Dialog](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) to get some syntax help on different JMeter Functions
- See [Functions and Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) chapter of JMeter User Manual to learn more about JMeter Functions
- Check out [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for advanced information on certain functions